# Hide central characters of an email address in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Given an email-string as below

```dart
String email = "namesurname@mail.com"
```

I'd like to show in my Flutter code a censored string, e.g:

```dart
"na******ame@mail.com"
```

I tried `email.replaceRange(2, email.length, "*" * (email.length - 2))` with output:

```dart
"na******************"
```

I'd like to stop the censorship before @, maybe 2 or 3 characters before.

Comment: Use [`email.indexOf('@')`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/indexOf.html) to find the index of the `@` character (if present).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
String email="demoemail@gmail.com";
var nameuser = email.split("@");
var emailcaracter=email.replaceRange(2,nameuser[0].length,"*" * (nameuser[0].length-2));
print(emailcaracter);
```

result :

```html
de*******@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to achieve what you want exactly:

```
String unconsore(String string, {int consoreLevel = 2}) {
  final parts = string.split("@");

  if (parts.length != 2) {
    // Handle the case where there is no "@" separator in the string
    return string;
  }

  final stringBeforeA = parts[0];
  final stringAfterA = parts[1];

  final unconsoredBeforeA = stringBeforeA.replaceRange(
      consoreLevel, stringBeforeA.length - consoreLevel, "*" * (stringBeforeA.length - consoreLevel * 2));

  return "$unconsoredBeforeA@$stringAfterA";
}

// example
print(unconsore("namesurname@mail.com")); // na*******me@mail.com
```